# invalid css in asset:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have an error when executing assets:precompile. The error is on my css syntax, but I have a lot of css files and don't know how to find the file and line to fix the error.

How can I see the file and line when executing assets:precompile ?

Comment: Can you paste the error message?

Comment: why don't you put your css through a validation tool http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

If you want more output/information then add --trace or check the logs.

> bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace